# Magento Duplicate Orders

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, opayo

I have a Magento site using version `1.6.2.0` with which I'm experiencing problems with duplicate orders.

Having researched the subject I have found mostly forum threads explaining that `1.4.x` had problems with duplicate orders and the solutions mentioned (even those on SO which I have found) merely suggest the user updates Magento to `>1.4`.

I have also found a proposed solution [here](http://www.kassner.com.br/en/2011/01/07/magento-slow/) but am reluctant to delete observers which will prevent downloadable purchases working.

I've also spotted the Array Of Death fix mentioned a few times (e.g. [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/113901/P75/)) but this problem isn't present in `1.6.x`, Zend appears to have resolved it.

There are a couple of Javascript hacks suggested whereby the Confirm Order button is hidden upon submission but Magento `1.6.x` already does this.

I have increased the payment gateway timeout configuration variable to 120 seconds and am as yet to see if it yields results. I can't test it as the problem is intermittent (and probably therefore caused by communication or lack thereof between the payment gateway and Magento).

I am using Sagepay as the payment gateway.

How might I further debug this?

Comment: We are having the same issue w/ magento 1.6.2 & SagePay. Did you have any success investigating this?

Comment: Unfortunately not! It is being investigated by a colleague at present but they've not found anything as far as I am aware. I will report back here if they do.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted is correct, but I wouldn't use their fix, I would just disable the Mage_Rss module.

Mage_Rss has several observers in it that call Mage::app()->cleanCache(...) in the checkout process, which is extremely expensive if your installation is using the default filesystem cache and it's gotten large.

I found the best thing for troubleshooting Magento performance problems is to wire up [Xhgui](http://phpadvent.org/2010/profiling-with-xhgui-by-paul-reinheimer) and do some profiling.  Reading call stacks will help your understanding of Magento immensely also.

Oh, and I don't know if this is true for Sagepay, but I went and fixed this problem completely for PayflowPro by rewriting the method that generates transaction IDs to use the quoteID instead of generating unique IDs on every invocation.  I started down the path of committing this back, but I'm on 1.4.2 still and don't have time to test in later versions and it's a pretty significant rewrite.  Guess I could just put it out there for someone else to run pass Moses...